# How to allow download on an Android device without BT if BT is in manifest

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-play

I have an app the optionally requires BT - so I put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

in the manifest.

The problem is that this filters out all Android devices which do not have BT.

But I need to make it optional! So they should be still compatible so that users can install the app from GooglePLay - I will just deactivate the BT option in the app in that case.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
              android:required="false"/>
```

This is what the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) say about Play Store filtering through use of permissions:

> In some cases, the permissions that you request through  can affect how your application is filtered by Google Play.
>
> If you request a hardware-related permission — CAMERA, for example — Google Play assumes that your application requires the underlying hardware feature and filters the application from devices that do not offer it.
>
> To control filtering, always explicitly declare hardware features in  elements, rather than relying on Google Play to "discover" the requirements in  elements. Then, if you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a android:required="false" attribute to the  declaration.

Comment: Unfortunately did not solve my problem - Is there a way to find out which filter did restrict the app from downloading?